# Opentok Video Chat UI Swift

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, videochat, tokbox

I'm integrating opentok video chat in my swift project. I was able to successfully do so using this [sample project](https://github.com/thepatrick/Opentok-HelloWorld-Swift). I wanted to add video chat UI and related methods in swift i.e. volume/ mute and flip camera buttons. While looking thru ios sdk samples in objective-c, it's unclear what methods are related to this functionality. How can I add this functionality to my swift project? Your input would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is possible in openTok please refer whole documentation of opentok here is the link for customizing the UI: https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/customize-ui/ios/